# c++ CALLBACK function type

Tags: c++, winapi, win32-process

I'm trying to create something like `MsgProc` in Win32.  When they declare the `MsgProc` function they have the `CALLBACK` type before it.  So, all I'm trying to is create my own messsage function that calls my function to process the messages.  It is basically the same thing when messages getting sent and processed.  My question is how can i create the Same process?.  An example would be great.

Comment: CALLBACK is a macro defined as __stdcall. It set the calling convention of the callback to that of the win32 API. Implementing a callback in your own code doesn't require this macro unless it deals with the Windows API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than the classics function pointers and function objects you may be interested by the new C++0x lambdas.

Here's an example of passing a lambda to a timer function.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void onInterval(DWORD interval, std::function<void ()> callback) {
  for (;;) {
    Sleep(interval);
    callback();
  }
}

int main() {
  onInterval(1000, []() {std::cout<<"Tick! ";});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're in C++, just use a function pointer in your class:

http://www.newty.de/fpt/fpt.html

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Boost, I would definitely give [Boost.Signals](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/signals.html) a shot, they provide the functionality you are looking for in a clean and safe way ([Boost.Signals2](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/signals2.html) even in thread-safe way.)